# Limit on the number of items in the regex

Tags: php, regex

Is there a limit on the number of items inside the "or" condition in the regular expression?

For example, in this example there are 2 elements:

```
(my|your)
```

In this example there are 3 elements:

```
(my|your|their)
```

Is there a maximum number of elements in the condition? 100? 1000? 10.000? Or can the maximum length of a regular expression be limited?

This is just a theoretical question for personal interest. I swear, I'm not going to put into the regular expression 10k words!

Comment: There is no theoretical limit, but a practical one in the specific implementation. Strings may not necessarily be guaranteed to have arbitrary length in the editor or parser you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard set limit, though regular expression are executed using RAM & CPU, which for extremely large expression might lack resources.

This does not bother Symfony developers though, who based their new routing mechanism explicitly on this feature: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-fastest-php-router

Answer (score 0):

Using the | operator in any regex is just like two different regex. So it depends on the system capabilities (eg RAM and CPU power) how many | operators you can have. The | operator is the most inefficient way to create an expression.